# LINQ to SQL GroupBy: Generating a 2 level hierarchical collection with a single DB trip

Tags: linq, group-by

Let's say I have a table in a database that has three columns: Agency ID, Name, and Value.

I want to get a collection of <Name, Value> pairs grouped by Agency ID.

How can I do this?  I tried something like below, which works, but makes a DB call for each agency!

```
from div in db.AgencyDivisionsENT
      group div by div.AgencyId into NamePairCollection
      select new KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<DivisionResults>>(NamePairCollection.Key,
             NamePairCollection.Select(k => new DivisionResults 
             { 
                     Name = k.Name, 
                     Value = k.Value
               ));
```

I want to end up with something like this: IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<NameValuePair>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid round-tripping with this type of query is to group on the client side - by calling .AsEnumerable():

```
db.AgencyDivisionsENT
  .Select (x => new { x.AgencyId, x.Name, x.Value } )
  .AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(...)       // AsEnumerable() forces grouping to happen on the client 
  .ToDictionary(...)
```

This is in no way inefficient - as long as:

- you select only the data you need from the server with the initial .Select statement
- if you need .Where statement to filter the data, it is placed before the .AsEnumerable
- you're selecting *detail* rows (as in this case) rather than just aggregates.

Comment: Brilliant!  .AsEnumerable() is the magic dust that makes it work the way I want.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using chain syntax it would be:

```
db.AgencyDivisionsENT
.GroupBy(x=>x.AgencyId)
.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, g=>g.Select(x=>new { k.Name, k.Value }).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  The GroupBy and ToDictionary lambdas were very helpful.  However, this still caused many round trips to the DB (one per agency).